# simple yes or no checkbox for forms

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox

I have inserted a checkbox in my form.

My code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"/>

if($checkbox = ($_POST['checkbox']) == '1')
        {
            $checkbox = "si";
        }
        else
        {
            $checkbox = "no";
        }
```

I would like that if the checkbox is checked i receive "yes" otherwise "no".
Thanks.

Comment: what is your problem here??

Comment: you don't need to do that value. simply `if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))` and  input without `value` attribute. I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written wrong if condition here, You cannot use assignment in conditions.

Also there is no need to assign value to any variable in checking condition, You can directly use `$_POST['checkbox']`. Like this,

```
if($_POST['checkbox'] == '1') {
   $checkbox = "si";
} else {
   $checkbox = "no";
}
```

---

**Update:**

A better option is to use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) which determine if a variable is set and is not NULL. Like this,

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
   $checkbox = "si";
} else {
   $checkbox = "no";
}
```

Program will go in if condition only when user has checked the checkbox. In above case value attribute for `<input>` is not required. So your HTML will look something like this,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: are you sure that he need that value attribute? Wont be better just `if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))` and input without `value` ?

Comment: Yeah just checking isset would be a better idea, i just tried helped OP in his way.

Comment: then you can edit and write both two choices :) I think it would be even better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$request['checkbox_name'] = $request['checkbox_name'] == null ? 'N' : 'Y'; //for default value
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.